# When did the NBA establish the first collective bargaining agreement ? What were the reasons leading up to this?

Tags: nba, labor-relations, cba

Always been curious of when the first CBA came about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From this [FAQ](https://webfiles.uci.edu/lcoon/cbafaq/salarycap.htm#Q5):

> Bob Cousy began to organize the NBA players in 1954, although the
>   league refused to recognize the union until 1957. A near strike at the
>   1964 All-Star game forced the league to adopt a pension plan. **The
>   first CBA was established in 1970**, and new agreements followed in
>   1973, 1976 and 1980. The 1976 CBA coincided with the settlement of the
>   "Oscar Robertson" suit, which was filed by the players association in
>   1970 to block the NBA-ABA merger. The 1976 agreement also provided
>   limited free agency through the elimination of "option" clauses that
>   bound players to teams in perpetuity.

From another [account](http://www.apbr.org/labor.html):

> **COUSY ORGANIZES THE PLAYERS**
>
> Economic conditions continued unchanged
>   through 1954, at which point Bob Cousy, the league's top player, began
>   to organize the NBPA, which would become the first team sports
>   player's union. Cousy began by writing to an established player from
>   each of the league's teams (Paul Arizin of Philadelphia, Carl Braun of
>   New York, Bob Davies of Rochester, Paul Hoffman of Baltimore, Andy
>   Phillip of Fort Wayne, Pollard, Dolph Schayes of Syracuse and Don
>   Sunderlage of Milwaukee) in hopes of encouraging solidarity among the
>   players. All but Phillip responded positively (of all the owners, Fort
>   Wayne's Fred Zollner, who owned a machine works plant, was the
>   staunchest union opponent and this prevented the Pistons players from
>   participating), and Cousy next went to NBA President Maurice Podoloff
>   at the January, 1955 NBA All-Star Game with a list of concerns:
>   **payment of back salaries to the members of the defunct Baltimore
>   Bullets club**; establishment of a twenty-game limit on exhibition
>   games, after which the players should share in the profits; **abolition
>   of the $15 "whispering fine"** which referees could impose on a player
>   during a game; payment of $25 expenses for public appearances other
>   than radio, television or certain charitable functions; establishment
>   of an impartial board of arbitration to settle player-owner disputes;
>   moving expenses for traded players; and **payment of player salaries in
>   ten installments rather that twelve**, to provide more money to players
>   cut during the season. Podoloff agreed to the payment of two weeks'
>   salary to six players who had played for Baltimore before the
>   franchise folded and committed to meeting with the player
>   representatives within two weeks over their concerns.

As the excerpts above show, players were unhappy with the financial arrangements that they had with the NBA. The players wanted a better pension, some control over the "whisper" fines that referees could impose, payment of back salaries to certain players, and to settle other working conditions and payments.

Comment: What was the "whispering fine"? It sounds shady :)